# React Aria Combobox does not filter the entries based on the input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, combobox, react-aria

Hello I'm using the Combobox from React aria I have followed official docs however once I enter something in the input there is no filtering happening. For instance if you write PHP in the combobox it still shows the rest of entries which is incorrect behavior.
I won't post the code for styling and types because it doesn't influence the behavior.
In a Listbox I have noticed that `state.collection.keyMap` is not being update, but that just my guess.

Here is my code

```
//Autocomplete wrapper
export const Autocomplete = ({
  options,
  isLoading,
  isDisabled
}: AutocompleteProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComboBox items={options} isDisabled={isDisabled}>
        {(item) => (
          <Item textValue={item.label} key={item.label}>
            <p>{item.label}</p>
          </Item>
        )}
      </ComboBox>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
// Combobox with hook to enclose all state
import { useComboBox } from "./useCombobox";

export { Item, Section } from "react-stately";

export function ComboBox<T extends object>(props: ComboBoxProps<T>) {
  const {
    buttonProps,
    inputProps,
    listBoxProps,
    buttonRef,
    inputRef,
    listBoxRef,
    popoverRef,
    state
  } = useComboBox(props);

  return (
    <Styled.Wrapper>
      <Styled.InputGroup isFocused={state.isFocused}>
        <Styled.Input
          {...inputProps}
          ref={inputRef}
          isFocused={state.isFocused}
          aria-label="label"
          placeholder="placeholder"
        />
        <Styled.Button {...buttonProps} ref={buttonRef}>
          <span aria-hidden="true">▼</span>
        </Styled.Button>
      </Styled.InputGroup>
      {state.isOpen && (
        <Popover
          popoverRef={popoverRef}
          triggerRef={inputRef}
          state={state}
          isNonModal
          placement="bottom start"
        >
          <ListBox {...listBoxProps} listBoxRef={listBoxRef} state={state} />
        </Popover>
      )}
    </Styled.Wrapper>
  );
}

// facade hook for managing the state
import * as React from "react";
import {
  useButton,
  useFilter,
  useComboBox as useAriaComboBox
} from "react-aria";
import { useComboBoxState } from "react-stately";
import type { ComboBoxProps } from "@react-types/combobox";

export const useComboBox = <T extends object>(props: ComboBoxProps<T>) => {
  const { contains } = useFilter({ sensitivity: "base" });
  const state = useComboBoxState({ ...props, defaultFilter: contains });

  const buttonRef = React.useRef(null);
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
  const listBoxRef = React.useRef(null);
  const popoverRef = React.useRef(null);

  const {
    buttonProps: triggerProps,
    inputProps,
    listBoxProps
  } = useAriaComboBox(
    {
      ...props,
      inputRef,
      buttonRef,
      listBoxRef,
      popoverRef
    },
    state
  );

  const { buttonProps } = useButton(triggerProps, buttonRef);

  return {
    buttonProps,
    inputProps,
    listBoxProps,
    buttonRef,
    inputRef,
    listBoxRef,
    popoverRef,
    state
  };
};
```

```
//Listbox and options
const OptionContext = React.createContext<OptionContextValue>({
  labelProps: {},
  descriptionProps: {}
});

export const Option = ({ item, state }: OptionProps) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLLIElement>(null);
  const { optionProps, labelProps, descriptionProps, isSelected } = useOption(
    {
      key: item.key
    },
    state,
    ref
  );

  return (
    <Styled.ListItem {...optionProps} $isSelected={isSelected} ref={ref}>
      <Styled.ItemContent>
        <OptionContext.Provider value={{ labelProps, descriptionProps }}>
          {item.rendered}
        </OptionContext.Provider>
      </Styled.ItemContent>
      {isSelected && <span role="img">✅</span>}
    </Styled.ListItem>
  );
};

export const ListBox = (props: ListBoxProps) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);
  const { listBoxRef = ref, state } = props;
  const { listBoxProps } = useListBox(props, state, listBoxRef);

  console.log("state.collection", state.collection.keyMap);

  return (
    <Styled.List {...listBoxProps} ref={listBoxRef}>
      {[...state.collection].map((item) => (
        <Option key={item.key} item={item} state={state} />
      ))}
    </Styled.List>
  );
};
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-rosalind-py0ply?file=/src/Combobox/Listbox/Listbox.styles.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I have used `items` as static list where I should have used the `defaultItems` instead, so the behaviour was correct since the list was hardcoded and component wasn't controlled. In wrapper component only change is to change the prop name like in snippet below:

```
//Autocomplete wrapper
export const Autocomplete = ({
  options,
  isLoading,
  isDisabled
}: AutocompleteProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComboBox defaultItems={options} isDisabled={isDisabled}>
        {(item) => (
          <Item textValue={item.label} key={item.label}>
            <p>{item.label}</p>
          </Item>
        )}
      </ComboBox>
    </div>
  );
};
```